# Create role programmaticaly

Tags: discount, promotions, role

I need to create the role for shipping programmaticaly.

My role:
If if insert into shopping cart code s0001-->quantity > 200 --> discount -10%

this is my code:

```
    $rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule');
$customer_groups = array(0, 1, 2, 3,4);
$rule->setName($sku)
  ->setDescription('')
  ->setFromDate('')
  ->setCouponType(0)
  ->setCouponCode(0)
  ->setUsesPerCustomer(0)
  ->setCustomerGroupIds($customer_groups) //an array of customer grou pids
  ->setIsActive(1)
  ->setConditionsSerialized('')
  ->setActionsSerialized('')
  ->setStopRulesProcessing(0)
  ->setIsAdvanced(1)
  ->setProductIds('')
  ->setSortOrder(0)
  ->setSimpleAction('by_percent')
  ->setDiscountAmount($discount)
  ->setDiscountQty(99999999999999)
  ->setDiscountStep(1)
  ->setSimpleFreeShipping('0')
  ->setApplyToShipping('0')
  ->setIsRss(0)
  ->setWebsiteIds(array(1));


$conditions = array(
        "1" => array(
                "type"              => "salesrule/rule_condition_product",
                "attribute"     => "sku",
                "operator"          => "==",
                "value"         => "$sku"

        ),
        "1--1" => array(
                "type"              => "salesrule/rule_condition_product",
                "attribute"         => "quote_item_qty",
                'operator'      => ">",
                'value'         => "$qty"
        )
    );

$rule->setData('conditions',$conditions);
```

The first part imported well.
What error?
Thanks
Ale

Comment: If if insert into shopping cart code s0001-->quantity > 200 --> discount -10%

"s0001" is sku or discount code?

Comment: "s0001" is a sku